# Android studio import github project unable to find java file?

Tags: android-studio

When I download a project from github and import this project in android studio, I can't find java file in my android studio view .

[image: as shown here]

And my folder has some java file .

[image]

Can you please help me to fix this problem?

Comment: What happened next after this line `When I download a project from github and import this project in android studio .`? It seems that your sentence is hanging. Thanks!

Comment: Your images are missing.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/xyshY

Comment: It is my images url .

Comment: try restarting android studio.

Comment: I restart several time but it can not fix it .

Comment: okay. than tell procedure how you are doing ?

Comment: I only see com.orangelabs package and click it not show file in it , but my system have java file in com.orangelabs.rcs.ri . For example RiApplication.java and  others . AndroidManifest.xml show me error , so that project can not work for me .